# Angular inspect a custom element and bind to local template variable

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-components, inspect

I'm using a date picker component from third-party module in my app and I want to access to some properties of the component like invalid property. in normal html element I can bind element with syntax like this:

```
<input #myvariable="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="inputModel">
```

But for this component the variable is always null

```
<dp-date-picker #myvariable="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="inputModel" ... ></dp-date-picker>
```

I couldn't find appropriate property or attribute in the modules documents to use for my extra needed functionality, so I need to inspect the element in some way.

Comment: if your "custom element" is not implements ControlValueAccessor, you can not asign a [ngModel] -neither use Reactive FormControl- Sure the control has a property to give value and a event when change so you can write -if imagine the property is "value" and the event change: `<dp-date-picker [value]="inputModel" (change)="inputModel=$event">`

Comment: Thank you @Eliseo I used event to access to element and ng-invalid class by event.path[x].classList.contains("ng-invalid"). It's not a tidy approach but I couldn't find efficient solution.